# grunt-contrib-watch + grunt-rsync

Tags: gruntjs, rsync, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and [grunt-rsync](https://github.com/jedrichards/grunt-rsync) to upload any file changes to my dev server. Here's my setup:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        ...

        watch: {
            upload: {
                files: ['*'],
            },
            ...
        },

        rsync: {
            options: {
                args: ['--verbose'],
                exclude: ['.*','node_modules','sql','artifacts','session','logs','cache'],
                recursive: true,
                syncDestIgnoreExcl: true
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    src: './',
                    dest: '/usr/local/project',
                    host: 'dev3',
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        if(target!=='upload') return;
        grunt.config('rsync.dev.options.src', filepath);
        grunt.task.run('rsync:dev');
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-rsync');
    ...
};
```

The `rsync` task works great on its own; it uploads my entire project relatively quickly but not quite fast enough to run on every file edit.

I'm trying to use `grunt.event.on` to modify the `src` just before running the task again so that it uploads just the one file. `grunt.task.run('rsync:dev')` doesn't seem to do anything at all, however. Doesn't error, nothing. Here's the output when I run it and then create a new file:

```
$ grunt watch:upload --debug --stack
Running "watch:upload" (watch) task
Waiting...OK
>> File "ppp" added.
```

If I give it an invalid task name, it does error out, so it obviously is looking for the task, I'm just not sure what it's doing with it. The file never makes it up to my server.

How can I get it to rsync just the files I've saved?

N.B. [newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/21) doesn't seem to work either, so I'm trying to do this manually via `grunt.event.on('watch'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with [Kyle's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456729/65387), `grunt-contrib-watch` is simply too slow (at least on linux). I found another library, [grunt-este-watch](https://github.com/steida/grunt-este-watch) which runs much quicker and lets you update the rsync config before every change without any hackery. My setup looks like this now:

```
esteWatch: {
    options: {
        dirs: [
            '**/',
            '!node_modules/**/',
            '!sql/**/',
            '!artifacts/**/',
            '!session/**/',
            '!logs/**/',
            '!cache/**/',
            '!plugins/ezc/**/',
        ],
        livereload: {
            enabled: true,
            port: 35729,
            extensions: ['css'],
        }
    },
    '*': function(filepath) {
        if(grunt.file.isMatch(['**/*___jb*'],filepath)) return []; // ignore temporary JetBrains files
        var tasks = ['rsync'];
        if(grunt.file.isMatch(grunt.config('uglify.dist.src'),filepath)) tasks.push('uglify');
        if(grunt.file.isMatch(grunt.config('less.dist.src'),filepath)) tasks.push('less');
        grunt.config('rsync.dev.options.src', filepath);
        grunt.config('rsync.dev.options.dest', path.join('/path/to/project',filepath));
        return tasks;
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Was slowly getting mad from all the sporadic hanging that `grunt-contrib-watch` does on Windows. `grunt-este-watch` is faster, cleaner, and more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advised to run tasks from within the `watch` event. Take a look at the warning here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event

Currently the best way to do the above is to configure your rsync task with the watch event but use the watch's `tasks` to run the task, like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    upload: {
      // Dont spawn to retain the process context here
      options: { spawn: false },
      files: ['*'],
      tasks: ['rsync:dev']
    },
  },
});
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  if (target === 'upload') grunt.config('rsync.dev.options.src', filepath);
});
```

FWIW, we're looking for better ways to handle the above use case. Here is the leading idea: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/156

Comment: I think it was the spawning thing that was screwing me up. Newer versions of watch have a [maximum call stack](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/72) issue. I downgraded back to 0.4.x but then this stopped working again. Had to change to change the option to `nospawn:true`

Comment: Even with this, however, Grunt restarts the watch on every file after every change. I have 19K files so this takes a few minutes, which is obviously way too slow. I need to get the entire process under about half a second.

Comment: That issue is different than your issue. Why are you watching 19K files? grunt-contrib-watch (nor AFAIK, any other watch currently in node.js) will handle 19K files, let alone in under 500ms.

Comment: Not on Ubuntu. I put it into verbose mode and I can see it creating a watch on every file, one at a time. I found another library, [grunt-este-watch](https://github.com/steida/grunt-este-watch) which only creates the watches on the directories and doesn't recreate them after every file change. Starts up in 1.5 seconds (~1775 directories) and then its lightning quick after that. It sometimes triggers an event on the `___jb_bak___` files my IDE creates, but those are easy to filter out. Further, it gives you a callback for each change so we don't need `grunt-newer`.

Comment: Glad that is working for you. I wish I had the luxury of abandoning my tests cases too :)